# Changing root and user passwords in MariaDB 10.5?

Tags: users, password, debian, mariadb-10.5, root

We have a few MariaDB servers (MariaDB 10.5, running on Debian 11/bullseye) where we need to change the passwords for the DB root user and for other user accounts in the DB system (by which I mean users in MariaDB itself, not Linux account passwords).

These DB servers were set up at varying times but are all at least a few years old, and the OS and DB packages have been upgraded in place since then.

I was uncertain of the correct way to update the DB root user password (it having been originally set via `mysql_secure_installation` way back whenever when(!)), but after some researching, it now seems to turn out that, [from MariaDB 10.4 onwards, MariaDB allows local root account access via unix_socket authentication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/).

In fact, it looks as though during one of the DB upgrades, the use of the previously set DB root password was dropped from our systems without us noticing (as we still had `.my.cnf` files, we didn't realise)? (See output below)

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)


MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE USER for root@localhost                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE USER `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Is there anything else that I also need to check, regarding what the current root access permissions are?

Although it is a bit counter-intuitive compared to the old world, the MariaDB rationale for this change seems reasonable, and therefore I presume there is actually no real need for me to try to set a new DB root password any more (although we have changed the Linux root user password, for reasons related to those that are also prompting these changes).

**Regarding changing passwords for other DB user accounts**, I am not sure whether I should be using the [SET PASSWORD](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-password/) or [ALTER USER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-user/) commands? Do they both do effectively the same thing (as far as just changing passwords is involved (ALTER USER can obviously do more))? Is there a reason to use one of these commands rather than the other?

Thanks for any advice.